# Can I use emoticons as class names in CSS? 

Tags: css, unicode, emoticons

When coding unicode CSS, is it allowed to use emoticons as class names? Should be possible I think, unicode is unicode. Or are there any restrictions?

Answer (score 6):

Yes! We! Can!

```css
div {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

div.:before,
div.:before {
  content: "Class " attr(class) ": ";
}

div.:after {
  content: "";
}

div.:after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
```

([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8somy46u/))

I will never use normal classs names again!